# A hashcode function that returns the same value for a string irrespective of the order of characters

Tags: java

I want to write a hash function that takes an input like ABC and BCA or BAC (basically any ordering of input characters, but the same characters) and returns the same value. I thought about returning the sum of their ASCII values, but that would not be unique.

Even if it's not totally unique, the best approximate would do (these would be used as keys in a Java HashMap.. so, any searching would eventually end up comparing the real values too. As such, its keys aren't strictly required to be unique, but the closer they're to being unique, the better will be the functioning of the HashMap)

Comment: Transform BCA and BAC to ABC by sorting the characters, then take to hashCode() of ABC.

Comment: Why not reorder the strings prior to applying the hash?

Comment: and what would be the benefit of doing this? How does putting ABC,BCA or BAC in the same hashmap buket help in anyway? You will unnecessarily create a wrapper around string.

Comment: Add `+`, multiply `*`, and xor `^` are all both commutative and associative, so you can use any of those operations to combine the ASCII values.

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve with this?

Comment: @NPE I'm trying to implement autocomplete. I have to display a concatenation of zip, city and area, whenever the person starts to type any substring of the city. For this, I plan to store all substrings of the city names as keys, with the corresponding concatenation as values. But this would really increase the map size. Therefore, I thought that at least, I will return the same hashcode for substrings that have the same characters (but in any order), and then, values in the corresponding bucket would be compared for actual substring comparison

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `char` array from the `String`, sort it, and then call the hashCode of that array:

```
String bca = "BCA";
char[] chars = bca.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(chars);
int hashCode = Arrays.hashCode(chars);
```

Comment: Rather than creating a new `String` just to call `hashCode()` on it, why not just call `Arrays.hashCode(chars)` after the sort?

Comment: @Andreas oh yeah, I didn't read the question completly. Anyway thanks!